# Discussion "Recovering Low-Rank Matrices From Few Coefficients In Any Basis"

Tags: compressive-sensing, reconstruction, projection

Existing work
concentrated mostly on the problem of “matrix completion”
where one aims to recover a low-rank matrix from randomly
selected matrix elements. Their result covers this situation as a
special case. I got many confusion of this paper.

Let's begin with the notation I already get confused. $T$ is a linear space, $\rho$ is a $n\times n$ Hermitian matrix of rank $r$. Let $P_U$ be the orthogonal projections onto $U=\mathrm{range}\ \rho$.

(1) The equation $\mathcal{P}_T(\sigma)=P_U\sigma+\sigma P_U-P_U\sigma P_U$ means the map $\mathcal{P}_T:\sigma\rightarrow P_U\sigma+\sigma P_U-P_U\sigma P_U$ projects onto $T$. But how comes the equation? I don't understand what's the meaning of each term of the equation above.
(2) What's the meaning of "The space of matrices $T= 
 \{\sigma|(\mathbb{I}-P_U)\sigma(\mathbb{I}-P_U)=0\}$($\mathbb{I}$ is identity martix), whose compression to ker$\rho$ vanishes will play an important role" ?

More information can be found in the paper "Recovering Low-Rank Matrices From Few Coefficients In Any Basis" https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.1879.
I made an addition, see the picture.
[image]